# Could not read html body of an email with javax.mail on MSExchange

Tags: html, jakarta-mail, exchange-server

I have the following code reading the inbox:

```
Properties props = System.getProperties();              
props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", inboxSettings.Protocol);
Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
store = session.getStore(inboxSettings.Protocol);
store.connect(inboxSettings.Host,inboxSettings.Username, readPassword(inboxSettings.PasswordPath));

inbox = store.getFolder("Inbox");
inbox.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);

Message messages[] = inbox.search(new FlagTerm(new Flags(Flag.SEEN), false));
FetchProfile fp = new FetchProfile();
fp.add(FetchProfile.Item.ENVELOPE);
fp.add(FetchProfile.Item.CONTENT_INFO);
inbox.fetch(messages, fp);
for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++)
{
    MimeMultipart mimeMultipart = (MimeMultipart) messages[i].getContent();
    BodyPart bodyPart = mimeMultipart.getBodyPart(i);
}
```

The problem I have is that all the html emails are read as plain text. I can't get the html markup of the message. And I need to forward these messages in the same html format.
When i read the same email from Google, the format is different and it is multipart/alternative and I search inside the first multipart and find both plain text and html. 
On MS Exchange I only get the plain text.

Anyone knows what this is about?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Exchange has a habit of reformatting messages to what it thinks they should be, ignoring what was actually sent.  If you have control over the mail server, you might be able to change some settings to help with this.  Otherwise, you're stuck with what Exchange gives you.  If it's not giving you the html version of the content, there's not much you can do.  But, you might want to use the msgshow.java demo program to dump out the entire content of the message to make sure the html content isn't really in there somewhere and you're just not accessing it correctly.